# Aplication crash on using PRISM 6 with UWP

Tags: c#, prism, uwp

I've referenced the following libraries in a new UWP project.

- Prism
- Prism.Unity.Windows
- Prism.Windows

After replacing the base class for app class with PrismUnityApplication I et an exception in the code

```
            var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView(Constants.InfrastructureResourceMapId);
```

in the following method

```
  public void RegisterFrame(IFrameFacade frame, String sessionStateKey)
```

in the class

```
 public class SessionStateService : ISessionStateService
```

The error message is : ResourceMap Not Found.

Have I missed a step some where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you did something wrong in the setup as I'm unable to reproduce the error with both the stable and pre-release packages. As described on Prism's [readme page](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), you should only install the Prism.Unity package and the rest will be pulled in accordingly.

> Note that adding the container-specific package to your project, will also pull in the correct platform-specific package and the core PCL library. E.g. when you'd like to use Unity in a WPF project, add the Prism.Unity package and the rest will be pulled in as well.

This will indeed pull in the references you mentioned, but only Prism.Unity package is added as a project reference. Your `project.json` file should look like this (depending on using stable or pre-releasem you'll have a different version of course):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0",
    "Prism.Unity": "6.2.0-pre1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

The next step is indeed replacing the base class with PrismUnityApplication in both C# and XAML files. Remove everything from the App class except from the constructor and the `OnLaunchApplicationAsync` method:

```
sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Running the app now, gives you this error since the MainPage file isn't moved yet.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Prism.Windows.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The page name Main does not have an associated
>   type in namespace App2.Views

Add a new blank page under the Views folder and everything should be running fine. Please try again following the above steps carefully.

You can find samples at https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Bart, I think arshadbadarkhan is having the same issue we were.

arshadbadarkhan, if you're like us, you are trying to model your new Prism6 app after the AdventureWorks reference implementation. We fixed this runtime issue by adding an easily overlooked folder and file from AW. When we copied this file:

...\Prism-Samples-Windows-master\Prism-Samples-Windows-master\AdventureWorks.Shopper\AdventureWorks.Shopper\Strings\en-US\Resources.resw

to a Strings/en-US folder in our new product's main application project, we avoided the ResourceMap not found error. Now we can take advantage of any default strings AW uses, and we have a repository to add our own strings in the future.

Comment: Thank you.. this was pain for me for quite some time.